# Android Search View not displaying any text

Tags: android, searchview

I am using search view . It was working before now its not responding, I cant see any text being typed in the Search View, also I am not getting back any call back when text is changed.

Here is the xml layout file,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cardsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is how I am setting SearchView Callback,

```
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

I am not getting any callbacks to these methods when I type in SearchView.

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        filterCards(newText);
        return false;
    }
```

I am implementing SearchView.OnQueryTextListener in my Fragment.

Thanks.

Comment: did you tried my solution?

Comment: please show  `filterCards(newText);`

Comment: @SohailZahid That method is never triggered when I type in to the SearchView

Answer (score -1):

Try to give,

```
 android:textColor="#000000"
```

to your `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

> `Note :` May be your text is white color, that's why you can't to see.

Comment: I dont think its the text color, As you can see I am changing the text color in code. I also tried your solution. Didn't work. If its the text color then I should get call back to the listener methods. Thats not happening